# Linking to jquery via https

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, https

I'm developing a login page, and being new, started off building just using http. Everything is working the way I expect to this point. Now I'm trying to limit access strictly via https. In my html head, I currently have:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/localhost/js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>`
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

However, when accessed via https, the link to jquery-ui.js gets blocked due to being insecure content. I can change the link to https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js, but then I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Property '#' of object # is not a function.", on line 8268 of jquery-2.0.2.js. If I download the jquery-ui.js file and link to it locally, everything works http and https. But why does it not work when hosted externally? Can someone explain why this is happening and what I can do to resolve it? Is there a benefit/drawback to hosting linked files locally versus externally? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to download jquery ui and include the version on your server (localhost). This way you send less data to google.

the benefit of hosting it externally is that the file might be already cached, because the user visited another page including it before, so it could improve the speed of your homepage.

it just doesn't work with `https://code.jquery.com` because code.jquery.com does not support ssl.

Comment: Just edited my post to reflect that I've done so. Just missed me. :)

Answer (score 7):

Try using the one from `Google CDN`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's definitely an option, but my concern is that something else not so apparent isn't working properly, that will later on come back to bite me once things start getting much more complicated. Either way, I appreciate your assistance! :)