# Link without touch html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page in an old CMS. It only allow me to put a img, but I cant put anymore.

The img have his own div class="flash".

I can add some script or css in the header, but I cant touch the html.... it possible to add a link to this image?

Thanks

Comment: can you add Div html and what link you want to add? also there are one or more divs with same type of structure? Add these in to your code

Comment: Yes, you can add an on-click event to the image using jquery, targeting it by using the class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the div with a link using jQuery like this:

```js
var x = "http://example.com"

$(".flash").replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<a href='" + x + "'>" + this.innerHTML + "</a>")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flash">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>
```

Comment: I add to header: 

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
var x = "http://example.com"

$(".flash").replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<a href='" + x + "'>" + this.innerHTML + "</a>")
});
</script>` but don't works :-(

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible you just need to use this,

```js
var image = $('.flash').find('img')[0].outerHTML;
var link = '<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">'+ image + '</a>';
$('.flash').html(link);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='flash'>
<img border="0" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/logo_w3s.gif" width="100" height="100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the jQuery tag on the question. I suggest you try to use [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) like so

```
$(".flash")
```

to select the class `.flash`

```
.wrap(<a href='https://google.com'></a>)
```

to wrap the element with the class `.flash` with the tags I added. Namely,

`<a href='https://google.com'></a>`

Full script put together:

```
$(".flash").wrap("<a href='https://google.com'></a>");
```

What this will do is render the markup like so:

`<a href='https://google.com'><img class="flash" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>`

If you click anywhere on the image it will take you to `https://google.com` or the `href` of the wrapper `<a>` tag.

You only need to add the script `$(".flash").wrap("<a href='example'></a>");` to your page. Change example.com to the link you want.

Working example:

```js
$(".flash").wrap("<a href='https://google.com'></a>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="flash" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
```

Comment: I add to my header:'`<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".flash").wrap("<a href='https://google.com'></a>");
    </script>`but don't works

Comment: @JuanMedina The script has to be loaded after jQuery. Try adding the script at the bottom of your footer.

Comment: Thanks again.... I do it but still don't works... you can see the code in the page https://www.handybag.es/

Comment: @JuanMedina The problem is that your website is served over `https` but the link to jQuery uses `http` and that causes the download of jQuery to be blocked. In summery, your page doesn't load jQuery and that's why the script in my answer doesn't work. You have to fix the link to jQuery first.

Comment: OMG..... I can`t upload a js to the server (I can't do many things with this CMS).... I fount this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156128/linking-to-jquery-via-https, but I use https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js bus still dosn't works.... do you know any solution?

Comment: Finally I solve it in other way, but in any case thanks a lot to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the window.open(url) command to do so. just add a click event to this class. for example:

```js
$(".flash").click(function(){
  window.open("http//wwww.google.com", '_blank');
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flash">click me</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thnks a lot... You and the others give more or less the same solution, but all of you give me two blocks of code and really I don't know where to put it... can you specify where I have to put it?

Comment: the first block is the one that you need. you can add it where ever you can on the page or on the js file that linked to this page, if you have an access to it. it should work. 
the best thing to do it to put it inside the docomunt.ready() command if you have it. if not just add the <script></script> tag in insert it inside it.

Comment: Thanks, I try to add this to the header:

`<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
$(".flash").click(function(){
  window.open("http//wwww.google.com", '_blank');
});

</script>`

But dont works.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the 'click' event to that 'flash' class.
for eg.

```
$('flash').click(function(){ 

    //Whatever you want is here 
});
```